# to scan a file and get the number of lines in the file and also assigning each line to a slot in an array

Tags: java, arrays, inputstream

```
public static void flipLines(Scanner input) {
    int count = 0;
    
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        count++;
    }

    String[] arrayLines = new String[count];;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        arrayLines[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
    }

    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i = i + 2) {
            String temp = arrayLines[i];
            arrayLines[i] = arrayLines[i + 1];
            arrayLines[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i = i + 2) {
            String temp = arrayLines[i];
            arrayLines[i] = arrayLines[i + 1];
            arrayLines[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLines.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arrayLines[i]);
    }
    input.close();
}
```

So basically in this program I'm supposed to scan an input file and writes to the console the same file’s contents with each pair of lines reversed in order. If the file contains an odd number of lines, leave the last line unmodified.

In order to do that I tried to use a while loop to get the count of total number of lines in a file and and then use another while loop to assign each line of the file to a slot in an array which i can later swap and print out.

But the thing about using two `while (input.hasNextLine())` is that after the first loop the scanner cursor stops at the end of the file and then the program is unable to read any lines. But if I only use one `while (input.hasNextLine())` then I can't get the count of lines and at the same time assign the lines to an array because the array doesn't have a size determined.

Can someone please help me around with this?

Comment: You don't really need to read all the lines, do you? Just two at a time, and then write them in the opposite order, then the next two, and write again. The only trick is to deal with the odd line and not try to read a line after it.

Comment: You could use the `java.nio.file.Files.lines()` method to count file lines in a text file but this would also count blank lines (if there are any).

Comment: You can also use an `ArrayList<String>` or `List<String>` which can grow dynamically. There is no need to get the file lines count. You can easily convert the List to an String[] Array (if you like) once  the file reading is complete: `String[] myStringArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);`.

Answer (score 1):

Read first line.
If there's more lines to read, read second line and print second line.
Print first line.
Repeat until there's no more lines to read.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("1\n2\n3\n4\n5");
while(s.hasNextLine()){
  String first = s.nextLine();
  if (s.hasNextLine())System.out.println(s.nextLine());
  System.out.println(first);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but the code isn't printing the last line if the number of lines are odd.

Comment: @AgrimChhibber It does for me.  Try it here:  https://onlinegdb.com/O2eyu5xNw